# Get iPhone iCloud mail address from Address Book

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, icloud, abaddressbook

I can get `home` (from `kABHomeLabel`), `work` (from `kABWorkLabel`), `other` (from `kABOtherLabel`) mail addresses.

But I can't figure out how to get `iCloud` mail address from Address Book.

**EDIT:**

Complete answer (thanks to Paulw11):

```
ABMultiValueRef emailsRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
for (int i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(emailsRef); i++) {
    CFStringRef currentEmailLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emailsRef, i);
    CFStringRef currentEmailValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailsRef, i);
    NSString *emailLabel = (__bridge NSString *)ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(currentEmailLabel);

    [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)currentEmailValue
                        forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Email",emailLabel] ];

    CFRelease(currentEmailLabel);
    CFRelease(currentEmailValue);
    emailLabel = nil;
}
CFRelease(emailsRef);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the method given in this answer -  [How to get Custom label and value of the Email in ABAddressBook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978099/how-to-get-custom-label-and-value-of-the-email-in-abaddressbook) - should allow you to get the labels for the email fields, including the iCloud label.